# How to print a string based on width height and depth

Tags: python

How can I print a string based on the width height and depth given by the user? In other words: how can I write a function that prints/return a string given by the user in different formats based on their selected width, height, and depth?

For example, if the user string is `.X.XXX.X..v.vXv.v.` and the given width is 3, the given height is 3, and the given depth is 2 it should print out:

```
.X.
XXX
.X.

.v.
vXv
.v.
```

Where the depth determines how many “blocks” of code there are (separated by a space).

All I can think of is:

```
def print_string(s, w, h, d):
    for i in range (0, int(len(s)/D), w):
        print (s[i:i+w])
    for i in range(0, len(s), D):
        print (“ “)
    for i in range (int(len(s)/D), len(s), w):
        print(s[i:i+w])
```

But that very much does not work.

Comment: This user has [asked this question before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74047755/839733). Also, exactly the same question asked by two other users within 30 minutes. Flagging. https://stackoverflow.com/q/74090007/839733

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested loops. Loop over every 2D block of text, then over every line for each 2D block. Like this:

```
def print_string(s, w, h, d):
    # per block
    for i in range(0, w * h * d, w * h):
        block = s[i:i + (w * h)]
        # per line
        for j in range(0, w * h, w):
            print(block[j:j + w])
        print("")


txt = input("input: ")
print_string(txt, 3, 3, 2)
```

Example run:

```
input: .X.XXX.X..v.vXv.v.
.X.
XXX
.X.

.v.
vXv
.v.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out = ''
for i, ch in enumerate(s):
    if i % w == 0:
        out += '\n'  # line separator
    if i % (w * h) == 0:
        out += '\n\n'  # block separator
    out += ch
print(out.strip())
```

Or, coming at it the other way round:

```
    for z in range(d):
        for y in range(h):
            for x in range(w):
                i = x + w * (y + (h * z))
                print(s[i], end='')
            print('')
        print('\n')
```

We call this [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

It works out to an index `i` of `h w z + w y + x`;
1st term gets us to start of block,
2nd term to start of line,
and 3rd term is position within that line.

Comment: I like the idea, but it doesn't produce the right output for some reason

Comment: I figured it out: You need to put `if i != 0:` before the other `if`s and remove the extra newline for blocks.

Answer (score 0):

##### One line solution

```py
'''
@parm s: string to printed
@parm h: height of each chunk
@parm w: weight of each chunk
'''
def print_format(s:str, h:int, w:int):
    print("".join([s[i] if (i+1)%w!=0 else (s[i]+"\n" if (i+1)%(w*h)!=0 else s[i]+"\n\n") for i in range(len(s))]))
```

#### Demo

```
print_format(".X.XXX.X..v.vXv.v.",3,3)
```

- Output

```
.X.
XXX
.X.

.v.
vXv
.v.
```

---

P.S.

- The one-line solution uses `height` and `weight` instead of `height` and `depth` cause it is more straightforward. However if needed, `weight` could be calculated through `depth`.
- The one-line solution also advanced in both memory and run-time performance.