# How to print a part of a string based on its width, height and depth

Tags: python, string, function, computer-science

Heyy, i have to create a function but I’m not sure how exactly to do it so any help would be appreciated. This is what I have to do:
Create a function that takes a string, integer x, integer of width, integer of height and integer of depth as inputs. This same function should return the x’th part of the string. If x isn’t valid it should return an empty string.

So for example:

```
       >>>function(‘v..xXXv..vVX.XX..v’, 0, 3, 3, 2)
       ‘ v..xXXv..’
       >>>function(‘v..xXXv..vVX.XX..v’, 1, 3, 3, 2)
       ‘vVX.XX..v’
```

I tried doing the following:

```
 def function(s, w, h, d):
     print(s[n*w: (n+1)*w*h])
```

This worked for the first example but not for the second, and also did not use the input of depth. How would I go about fixing this and creating this function?

Comment: similar questions are here [how-to-print-a-string-based-on-user-input-of-height-and-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74047755/how-to-print-a-string-based-on-user-input-of-height-and-width) and [how-to-print-a-string-based-on-width-height-and-depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74090067/how-to-print-a-string-based-on-width-height-and-depth)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a string based on width height and depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74090067/how-to-print-a-string-based-on-width-height-and-depth)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def string_splitter(string, x, width, height, depth):
    if x < 1 or x > width * height * depth:
        return ''
    else:
        return string[(x - 1) * (len(string) // (width * height * depth)) : x * (len(string) // (width * height * depth))]
```